# C# generics issue that is not present in Java

Tags: java, c#, generics

I'm having some difficulties understanding how csharp's generics work compared to Java ones.

I have written the following example in both c# and java

java

```java
abstract class Gun { }

class Laser extends Gun { }

class Flamethrower extends Gun { }

abstract class GunConfig<T extends Gun> { 
    public T gun;
}

class LaserConfig extends GunConfig<Laser> { }

class FlamethrowerConfig extends GunConfig<Flamethrower> { }

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      GunConfig[] configs = new GunConfig[2];
      
      configs[0] = new FlamethrowerConfig();
      configs[1] = new LaserConfig();
      
      System.out.println(configs[0]);
      System.out.println(configs[1]);
    }
}
```

csharp

```cs
abstract class Gun { }

class Laser : Gun { }

class Flamethrower : Gun { }

abstract class GunConfig<T> where T : Gun { 
    public T gun;
}

class LaserConfig : GunConfig<Laser> { }

class FlamethrowerConfig : GunConfig<Flamethrower> { }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GunConfig<Gun>[] configs = new GunConfig<Gun>[2];
        
        configs[0] = new FlamethrowerConfig();   // <--- Cannot implicitly convert 'FlamethrowerConfig' into 'GunConfig<Gun>'
        configs[1] = new LaserConfig();

        Console.WriteLine(configs[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(configs[1]);
    }
}
```

Before adding the generic type to the GunConfig class I had something like this

```cs
abstract class GunConfig { 
    public Gun gun;
}

class LaserConfig : GunConfig { 
    public void DoSomething() {
        var laser = (Laser)gun;
    }
}
```

I simply used to cast the base Gun instance to whatever my class was supposed to use, that make it so you can have a LaserConfig instance with another type of Gun based instance inside which would make the cast fail.

Comment: Struggled two days this week with a nearly similar issue. If there is no special need for having the generic in the GunConfig class I would recommend  sticking with Gun gun instead of T gun

Comment: And you would have to make DoSomething generic.

Comment: Yeah I'll probably write the code a bit differently so that the GunConfig is not generic and doesn't need that one T instance. I think it'll pop out somewhere else though and I'm not sure if I'm just bad at designing code or I'm missing some concepts. Either way thank you!

Comment: A hint is the warning emitted by the Java compiler.  If you don’t see it, enable all warnings and compile again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another non-generic `GunConfig` class and derive `GunConfig<T>` from it - to circumvent that collection typeparameter issue. It's a little annoying with the extra class you don't really need outside the collection, but actually only one or two more lines of code.

```
abstract class Gun { }

class Laser : Gun { }

class Flamethrower : Gun { }

abstract class GunConfig { // this resolves the type mismatch issue
}

abstract class GunConfig<T> : GunConfig where T : Gun { 
    public T gun;
}

class LaserConfig : GunConfig<Laser> { }

class FlamethrowerConfig : GunConfig<Flamethrower> { }

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        GunConfig[] configs = new GunConfig[2];
        
        configs[0] = new FlamethrowerConfig();   // no error now
        configs[1] = new LaserConfig();

        Console.WriteLine(configs[0]);
        Console.WriteLine(configs[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems one step closer to the final solution but there's still a problem: what if I want to access the gun property? I can't move that property inside my non-generic GunConfig class right?

Comment: Two possibilities (that I know of): 
a) You need to cast. Either by testing all available known implementations (Firethrower, Laser etc) or by adding a property to the non-generic base class that points out the type.
b) The real clean and elaborate way would be to not need the T parameter at all. This is achievable if all you ever want to do with a Gun inside GunConfig is done by the implementation in Gun. So you have the polymorphism inside impls of Gun and in GunConfig you dont need to even know what impl you deal with, just need to invoke it or assign or pass it to the next method etc...

Comment: I think I'll opt for the first option which is what I already had. I will try and implement the second option just out of curiosity, thank you!